# Thucydides Reports have no data

Tags: selenium, intellij-idea, jbehave, thucydides

Thucydides Reports have no data

I am trying to genrate Thucydides report by looking into [Demo Project](https://github.com/thucydides-webtests/thucydides-simple-demo). But my report always shows zero data. However, I can see some data in requirements, stories and capabilities

```
Test Result Summary

Test Type   Total   Pass    Fail    Pending     Ignored 
Automated      0    0 (0%)  0 (0%)  0 (0%)  0 (0%)
Manual         0    0 (0%)  0 (0%)  0 (0%)  0 (0%)     
Total          0    0 (0%)  0 (0%)  0 (0%)  0 (0%)
```

I saw the following exception in fail safe reports

```
1) Error injecting constructor, java.lang.VerifyError: class com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.guava.deser.HostAndPortDeserializer overrides final method deserialize.(Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonParser;Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/DeserializationContext;)Ljava/lang/Object;
at net.thucydides.core.reports.json.jackson.JacksonJSONConverter.<init>(JacksonJSONConverter.java:32)
while locating net.thucydides.core.reports.json.jackson.JacksonJSONConverter
at net.thucydides.core.guice.ThucydidesModule.configure(ThucydidesModule.java:57)
while locating net.thucydides.core.reports.json.JSONConverter

1 error
at sun.misc.Service.fail(Service.java:137)
at sun.misc.Service.access$200(Service.java:128)
at sun.misc.Service$LazyIterator.next(Service.java:301)
at net.thucydides.core.reports.ReportService.getDefaultReporters(ReportService.java:171)
at net.thucydides.core.ThucydidesReports.getReportService(ThucydidesReports.java:12)
at net.thucydides.jbehave.ThucydidesReporter.getReportService(ThucydidesReporter.java:96)
at net.thucydides.jbehave.ThucydidesReporter.generateReports(ThucydidesReporter.java:472)
at net.thucydides.jbehave.ThucydidesReporter.afterStory(ThucydidesReporter.java:452)
at org.jbehave.core.reporters.DelegatingStoryReporter.afterStory(DelegatingStoryReporter.java:49)
at org.jbehave.core.reporters.ConcurrentStoryReporter.afterStory(ConcurrentStoryReporter.java:119)
at org.jbehave.core.embedder.StoryRunner.runBeforeOrAfterStories(StoryRunner.java:85)
at org.jbehave.core.embedder.StoryManager.runBeforeOrAfterStories(StoryManager.java:91)
at org.jbehave.core.embedder.StoryManager.runStories(StoryManager.java:86)
at org.jbehave.core.embedder.Embedder.runStoriesAsPaths(Embedder.java:203)
at net.thucydides.jbehave.runners.ThucydidesReportingRunner.run(ThucydidesReportingRunner.java:157)
... 9 more
```

Caused by: com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Guice provision errors:

Can any one help on this problem

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like there is some dependency conflict with my POM file. I have added the dependency management in the pom file and all goes well.

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-joda</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.3</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```